# MenuBar widget in Vaadin Flow (Vaadin 10) missing?

Tags: widget, vaadin, menubar, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

Vaadin Framework (Vaadin 8) offers a [`MenuBar`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.html) widget, as [discussed in the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-menubar.html), and [shown in the Sampler](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/interaction/menu-bar).

When I switch the manual to "Vaadin 10" mode, I cannot find the `MenuBar` widget. I know Vaadin 10 (Vaadin Flow) is a major re-write of Vaadin, is the widget changed in name or not yet available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Possibly in Vaadin 14

**Update:** A `MenuBar` widget is planned for development by Vaadin Ltd, scheduled for Vaadin 14 release.

- [See the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components.html).
- On GitHub, see Issue # 4694 [*MenuBar component*](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4694).

## No `MenuBar` in Vaadin 10 or 11

As discussed in [this Forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17167715/17168060), as of version 11.0.1, [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow) currently lacks any such menu bar widget.